# Can't get the right float value from EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So I am trying to read `float` values using `EditText` but I always seem to get back the value of `0.0` that I initialised it to in all cases.

**Java code:**

```
  try {
        //To get weight
        EditText W = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        //Weight = Float.valueOf(W.getText().toString());
        //String weight = W.getText().toString();
        Weight = Float.valueOf(W.getText().toString());

        //To get height
        EditText H = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.height);
        Height = Float.valueOf(H.getText().toString());

        //To get age
        EditText A = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Age);
        Age = Float.valueOf(A.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

**XML code for one of them:**

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/da"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

> **Note:** I am using fragments not activites

Comment: Debug your application. What's the value of `W.getText().toString()`?

Comment: I suspect that an Exception is thrown (probably by the first `valueOf`), caught and then discarded (because you don't call `e.printStackTrace()`, leaving your float variables at the initialition value of `0.0`.

Comment: @f1sh it gives me '0.0' , the value that I initialised it to

Comment: can you see if there's an Exception? Put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block and look at the console output or logcat

Comment: @f1sh I have got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wake lock not active  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `EditText` is in the `onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I believe inputType should be set to numberDecimal instead of just number. Thanks

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Comment: Even if the value was a `number` and not a `numberDecimal`, it could still be parsed to a `float` using `valueOf`.